# Regarding C# Xml Reading

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently doing a XML file that includes the "name" of the city, the "region", "lat" latitude and "lng".

Here is my Code:

```
XmlDocument XmlFile = new XmlDocument();
try {
    XmlFile.Load("..\\..\\liste.xml");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Erreur" + ex.Message);
};
XmlNodeList MyNodeXML = XmlFile.GetElementsByTagName("city");
foreach (XmlNode unNode in MyNodeXML)
{
    string nomVille = unNode.Attributes[0].Value;
    string lat = unNode.Attributes[1].Value;
    string lng = unNode.Attributes[2].Value;
    listeCooVilles.Add(nomVille, new PointF(float.Parse(lat), float.Parse(lng)));
}
```

Where listeCooVilles is a Dictionnary.

Here is my XML: I did a sample for test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cities>
    <city>
        <name>Abercorn</name>
        <region>Montérégie</region>
        <lat>45.032999</lat>
        <lng>-72.663057</lng>
    </city>
<cities>
```

I saw many post doing the same as above in StackOverflow, but I still get an IndexOutOfRange Exception on the line

```
string nomVille = unNode.Attributes[0].Value;
```

Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: don't see any attributes?  name/region etc are elements

Comment: there are no attributes in your xml, so you will always get a exception. You should go for the child nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  element has no attributes - only sub-elements. Attributes are name=value pairs at the same level as the element. E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cities>
  <city name="Abercorn" region="Montérégie" lat="45.032999" lng="-72.663057" />
  <city name="Granby" region="Montérégie" lat="45.4" lng="-72.733333" />
</cites>
```

Nesting elements (as you have done originally) and using attributes (as you've coded for) are both equally valid ways of structuring your XML document.

Comment: There is no way of doing the way I written my XML?

Comment: Sure there is... take a look at the XmlReader class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 5):

As pointed our those are elements not attributes. Your code needs to change to this:

```
    nomVille = unNode.Item["name"].Value
    region = unNode.Item["region"].Value
    lat = unNode.Item["lat"].Value
    lng = unNode.Item["lng"].Value
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the nodes in your XML sample have attributes, which is why the collection has `null` elements in it.

Try changing it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cities>
    <city testAttr = "hello!">
        <name>Abercorn</name>
        <region>Montérégie</region>
        <lat>45.032999</lat>
        <lng>-72.663057</lng>
    </city>
<cities>
```

The addition of the `testAttr` should provide a valid collection in `unNode.Attributes`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using attributes in city tag but I think you should be using  xml elements.